# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte (microsoft API)

Tags: azure, python-2.7, unicode, character-encoding, ascii

I'm trying to parse some text to use in write some text which contains special characters (my code is written in Python 2.7) and keep on having the same ascii error. Here's what I have so far:

first line:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

then within a function I specify the reference text to send:

```
self.referenceText=u"波构".encode('utf-8')
self.pronAssessmentParamsJson = "{\"ReferenceText\":\"%s\",\"GradingSystem\":\"FivePoint\"}" % self.referenceText;
```

Unfortunately when the program reaches the line 2. That's is when parsing the literal %s (special characters) with the other text. The error message is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

(Those steps are taking from the official example: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Cognitive-Speech-TTS/blob/master/PronunciationAssessment/Python/sample.py)

Thanks for your help

Comment: I tried that code and it is valid python 3. Is there a reason for using python 2? It reached end of life more than a year ago. Unicode handling was notoriously difficult, here are some tips: https://pythonhosted.org/kitchen/unicode-frustrations.html

Comment: Unfortunately yes, I have some constraints and the code has to be written in Python 2 :(

Comment: Do you have `from __future__ import unicode_literals` active? Otherwise I don't understand why Python 2 would want to decode the formatting argument. If that's the case, encode only *after* applying the `%` operation, not before.

Comment: Btw, are you aware of the `json` module? It might save you some trouble. For example, if `referenceText` contains a quote or newline character, you'll end up with invalid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem with the following (simplified but runnable) code snippet:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
referenceText = u"波构".encode('utf-8')
pronAssessmentParamsJson = '{"ReferenceText":"%s"}' % referenceText
```

The above runs fine without exception in Python 2.7.17.

However, I can reproduce the UnicodeError with the following modified version (note the `u` prefix before the second string literal):

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
referenceText = u"波构".encode('utf-8')
pronAssessmentParamsJson = u'{"ReferenceText":"%s"}' % referenceText
```

Or with this one:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
referenceText = u"波构".encode('utf-8')
pronAssessmentParamsJson = '{"ReferenceText":"%s"}' % referenceText
```

The `unicode_literals` directive has the effect that all string literals are treated as if you prefixed them with `u`.

The problem here is implicit coercion:
First you encode `u"波构"` from type `unicode` to type `str` explicitly using UTF-8.
But then the string formatting with `%` coerces it back to `unicode`, because if one of the operands is `unicode`, the other one has to be too.
The literal `u'{"ReferenceText":"%s"}'` is `unicode`, and therefore Python attempts to automatically convert the value of `referenceText` from `str` to `unicode` as well.

Apparently, automatic conversion happens with `.decode('ascii')` behind the scenes, not with `.decode('utf8')` or some other codec.
And of course, this fails miserably:

```
>>> u"波构".encode('utf-8')
'\xe6\xb3\xa2\xe6\x9e\x84'
>>> u"波构".encode('utf-8').decode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

One solution would be to defer manual encoding to a later stage, in order to avoid implicit coercion:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
referenceText = u"波构"
pronAssessmentParamsJson = u'{"ReferenceText":"%s"}' % referenceText
pronAssessmentParamsJson = pronAssessmentParamsJson.encode('utf-8')
```

However, since you are obviously trying to serialise JSON, you should really be doing this:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({'ReferenceText': u"波构"})
'{"ReferenceText": "\\u6ce2\\u6784"}'
```

Otherwise you'll soon run into trouble if `referenceText` contains eg. quotes or newline characters.